# Does data imputation impose any change to data structure?

Tags: python, autoencoder, imputation

Does anyone know if data imputation changes the structure of a dataframe?
I am running a deep Model, which it works quite good, but as soon as I impute the data it stops working!

I tried two methods

1- Mean Imputation

```
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    data_mean = data_mis_05.copy(deep=True)
    mean_imputer = SimpleImputer (strategy='mean')
    data_mean.iloc[:,:]= mean_imputer.fit_transform(data_mean)
```

2- KNN imputation

```
    from fancyimpute import KNN
    knn_imputer = KNN()
    dataKNN = data_mis_05.copy(deep= True)
    dataKNN.iloc[:,:]=knn_imputer.fit_transform(dataKNN)
```

I am getting this error when I am running a Deep Learning model on the imputed data, while the code is running for the same dataset before Imputation

````
    RuntimeError: index 5 is out of bounds for dimension 4 with size 5 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Following the example in the sklearn documentation, but adapting to a pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

df = pd.DataFrame([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9]])
df.head()

imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

If we pass a dataframe directly, it will transform it into a numpy array:

```
df = imp_mean.fit_transform(df) 
type(df)
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

We could simply convert the array back into a DataFrame or save the new values and overwrite it later:

```
new_values = imp_mean.fit_transform(df)
new_values = pd.DataFrame(new_values)
df.iloc[:, 2] = new_values.iloc[:, 2]
```

Comment: I tried this but the error is still there, I updated the port with the error I am getting